# I can't find 'Add all tracks' in the add to playlist section in iOS 7

Tags: playlist, ios, mediaplayer, music.app

With iOS 7 the "Add all tracks" option, when selecting a playlist, seems to have vanished.
Now the user has to select each song in the playlist individually, which can be very tedious with a long playlist.

How can I get back the "Add all tracks" option?

Comment: This seemed to be the only solution to the lack of "add to up next" on the iPhone. I want it back...

Comment: I tried this route and this doesn't eve work!

Answer (score 2):

After contacting a local Apple Store, I was informed that, the feature "Add all tracks" used in the playlist has been removed, and now you have to manually add each song or use iTunes to make the Playlist !!